# Javascript code equivalent of pressing enter

Tags: javascript, automatic-updates

i am trying to submit the form automatically using javascript. But unable to do so. 
Below is the target submit.

`<input id="jpform:jpsubmit" type="submit" name="jpform:jpsubmit" value="Submit" tabindex="3" onclick="return validateJPJD();">`

I have tried below steps. But doesn't work.

Javascript:

```
function Travel() {
    return validateJPJD();
}
Travel()`

document.getElementById('jpform:jpsubmit').onclick();

document.getElementById('jpform:jpsubmit').submit();
```

Can someone please help me?

Alternatively, This form get submitted with enter button. But i dont the equivalent of this as well.

Comment: That’s a submit button. Where’s the form? (You can call `.click()` on the submit button, but `.submit()` on the form is nicer.)

Comment: There is no such method `onclick()` on `button` element maybe you've meant `click()`?

Comment: You should not call `submit()` on the button, but rather on the form element.